# Finding Distinct Words between 2 sentences in java

Tags: java, data-structures, unique, words

What is an efficient way to find out all the unique words between 2 sentences in java and store them? What data structure should be used to store the words?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "unique words between 2 sentences"? Also, if this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: unique meaning all distinct words in the 2 sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Store words from the first sentence in hashset and then iterate over ords in second sentence to see if its already there in hashset

Answer (score 0):

Put all words from one sentence in a set, then pass through words of the second sentence. If the word exists in a set, take it out of the set, otherwise put it into the set.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of achieving this is:

```
//I   use regular expression to remove punctuation marks
//II  use split to convert the sentences into collections of "words"
//III create a variable that is an implementation of java.util.set (to store unique words)
//III iterate over the collections 
//    add words from each sentence to the set variable (that way the word will only be stored once)
```

Hope this helps